# Isolated vertex, do you think it's still a probabilistic graph?

Tags: probability, graph-theory

Provided that an implication whose antecedent is false is always true, I am wondering if an oriented, weighted graph with $2$ vertices connected by arcs and a $3^{rd}$ vertex alone, isolated from the two others is still a probabilistic graph?

Definition of probabilistic graph says that

> For each vertex, the sum of the weights of the arcs going out from it must be $1$

But here, the $3^{rd}$ vertex has no arcs going out from it, so the above mentioned condition is satisfied?

EDIT : What confuses me is that the transition matrix of such a graph does not meet the requirement that the sum of the coefficients of each line is $1$

Comment: Summing over an empty set produces 0, not 1.

Comment: If you wanted something as close as possible to the isolated vertex, you could have a vertex $v$ with a loop from $v$ back to $v$ of weight $1$, with no other arcs out of $v$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For each vertex, the sum of the weights of the arcs going out from it must be $1$

You seem to be interpreting this as an "if-then" statement, something like "If there are any arcs going out from $V$, then the sum of their weights must be 1".  Your reasoning is then that if there are no arcs going out from $v$, then the statement is vacuously true.

But that's not what the statement says.  Regardless of whether there are any arcs coming out from $V$, it says to sum over the set of weights of the arcs.  If there are no arcs, then you are summing over an empty set, and in that case the sum of the weights is zero, not 1.  So the condition is not satisfied in this case.